# Validate Month Year Format

Tags: regex, date-format

I need to validate Text box in this format (ex:FEB 2014 MMM YYYY).

I am using the following regular expression string

```
^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\-\d{4}$
```

Only issue is that my input is with a 'space' and not '-' i.e. JUN 2012 not JUN-2012

Can someone please amend the above regex to cater for space

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `\s` instead of `\-` in your regex

like this :

```
^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\s\d{4}$
```

@Avinash is right \s matches `[\r\n\t\f]` better use " " instead.

Comment: Can we have both space and hyphen included

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex to match month and year in this `MMM YYYY` format ,

```
^(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) \d{4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/13)