# Match characters and digits of fixed length and one occurance in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list in Python with values

```
['JUL_2018', 'AUG_2018', 'SEP_2018', 'OCT_2018', 'NOV_2018', 'DEC_2018', 'JAN_2019', 'FEB_2019', 'MAR_2019', 'APR_2019', 'MAY_2019', 'JUN_2019', 'MAT_YA_1', 'MAT_TY_1', 'YTD_YA_1', 'YTD_TY_1', 'L3M_YA_1', 'L1M_YA_1']
```

I want to match only strings where length is 8 and there are 3 characters before underscore and 4 digits after underscore so I eliminate values not required. I am interested only in the MMM_YYYY values from above list.

Tried below and I am not able to filter values like `YTD_TY_1` which has multiple underscores.

```
        for c in col_headers:
            d= (re.match('^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z0-9])[A-Z_0-9\d]{8}$',c))
            if d:
                data_period.append(d[0])
```

Comment: How about simply: `[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{4}`

Comment: `reg = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}$')` and then `data_period = list(filter(reg.search, col_headers))`

Comment: `reg = re.compile(r'^(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-9]{4}$')` and then `data_period = list(filter(reg.search, col_headers))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** based on @WiktorStribiżew observation that `re.match` does not require a full string match in Python

The regex I am using is based upon the one that @dvo provided in a comment:

```py
import re

REGEX = '^[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{4}$'
col_headers = ['JUL_2018', 'AUG_2018', 'SEP_2018', 'OCT_2018', 'NOV_2018', 'DEC_2018', 'JAN_2019', 'FEB_2019', 'MAR_2019', 'APR_2019', 'MAY_2019', 'JUN_2019', 'MAT_YA_1', 'MAT_TY_1', 'YTD_YA_1', 'YTD_TY_1', 'L3M_YA_1', 'L1M_YA_1']
regex = re.compile(REGEX)
data_period = list(filter(regex.search, col_headers))
```

Once again, based on a comment made by @WiktorStribiżew, if you do not want to match something as `"SXX_0012"` or `"XYZ_0000"`, you should use the regex he has provided in a comment:

```py
REGEX = r'^(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-9]{4}$'
```

Comment: This a wrong solution, as `re.match` does not require a full string match in Python. Besides, it will also match non-month data. See [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034837/validate-month-year-format).

Comment: @WiktorStribizew, thanks for your comment. I haven't dug into this module too much.

Comment: @0tKali It will actually match `EED_0000` - do you want this match?

Comment: I dont mind, Yes I would want to match such values as well so that I know something is wrong with the data

Comment: Comments from dvo , WiktorStribiżew and lmiguelvargasf are extremely helpful. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @0tKali, no worries, I appreciate you validated my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew, Sir, you are really good for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use regex for this, you should just try to parse it as a date in the first place:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_fmt = "%b_%Y"
for c in col_headers:
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(c, date_fmt)
        data_period.append(c) # Or just save the datetime object directly
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The part of this code that is actually doing the matching in your solution is this

```
[A-Z_0-9\d]{8}
```

The problem with this is that you're asking to find exactly 8 characters that include `A-Z`, `_`, `0-9`, and `\d`. Now, `\d` is equivalent to `0-9`, so you can eliminate that, but that doesn't solve the whole problem, the issue here is that you've encased the entire solution in brackets `[]`. Basically, your string will match anything that is 8 characters long and includes the above characters, ie: A_19_KJ9

What you need to do is specify that you want exactly 3 `A-Z` characters, then a single `_`, then 4 `\d`, see below:

```
[A-Z]{3}_\d{4}
```

This will match anything with exactly 3 `A-Z` characters, then a single `_`, then 4 `\d`(any numeric digit)

For a better understanding of regex, I'd encourage you to use an online tool, like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)